# Widget centers horizontally on story-board but not on phone

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9

When I select a widget in the story-board and click

```
Editor > Align > Horizontally in Container
```

the widget will be shifted and centered within the story board layout, however, when I install the app on my phone, the widget is not centered.

Is this behavior expected? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that does is position the element ***during*** design work.

You also have to set constraints to position the element at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by selecting the object and going to the constraints toolbar at the bottom and select **Horizontal center in container**.